# How to Implement Custom Error Pages with Application Insights

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-application-insights

I recently implemented Application Insights into my MVC C# app.  I was able to confirm the logging including error messages like 404.  I updated my web config to use a custom error page instead of the ugly default.  However, errors are no longer logged with Application Insights - just the fact that the error page was called.

I assume I have two options.

1) I turned off the custom error config and set a break point in the AiHandleErrorAttribute.cs file that was automatically added when I added Application Insights.  I was hoping to redirect to my error page after the exception but the break point was never reached.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)] 
public class AiHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext != null && filterContext.HttpContext != null && filterContext.Exception != null)
        {
            //If customError is Off, then AI HTTPModule will report the exception
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
            {   
                var ai = new TelemetryClient();
                ai.TrackException(filterContext.Exception);
                //redirect to error page - never gets called
            } 
        }
        base.OnException(filterContext);
    }
}
```

2) Call Application Insights from my controller for the error handling page, however, there are no errors (at least that I can tell) once I land/get redirected to my error handling page.

```
public class ErrorHandlerController : Controller
{
    // GET: ErrorHandler
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var ai = new TelemetryClient();
        ai.TrackException(can't find exception at this point);
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do this:

```
  var exceptionHandlerPathFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
    ai.TrackException(exceptionHandlerPathFeature.Error);
```